# Getting a segfault. Why?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segfault on `grid[x][y] = rand();`
Any help? I've tried replacing the random function call with a number to see if thats what was causing the problem but it doesnt seem so.. I've got no idea

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

int x;
int y;
int gridMult;
int grid[gridMult][gridMult];

srand(time(NULL));

std::cout << "Enter grid size:: ";
std::cin >> gridMult;

while(x < gridMult){
    while(y < gridMult){
        grid[x][y] = rand();
        y++;
    }
x++;
}

for(int x = 0; x < gridMult; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < gridMult; y++){
        std::cout << grid[x][y];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the initial values of x and y?

Comment: Move `int grid[gridMult][gridMult];` after `std::cin >> gridMult;`

Comment: You are initializing array `grid` with value `gridMult`, which is undefined, you loaded value into `gridMult` after array was creates, and that isn't what you wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In those two lines

```
int gridMult;
int grid[gridMult][gridMult];
```

`gridMult` is undefined, so how do you expect the compiler to properly size up your array?

---

Then when you get to the loops:

```
while(x < gridMult){
    while(y < gridMult){
        grid[x][y] = rand();
```

`x` and `y` are also undefined.

In general, I'd change those loops to `for` (or range-`for`) to scope the iteration variables as narrowly as possible.

---

If you want it to allocate dynamically based on user input, use `std::vector` and `resize` it to the desired size.

I'd also add that 2-dimensional arrays are typically realized on a 1-dimensional storage vector and 2-dimensional view on top of it, instead of nested vectors, so you might want to read about those patterns.

Comment: even if `gridMult` is defined, `int grid[gridMult][gridMult];` is still not allowed in C++

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc True. But I felt that focusing on *solutions*, not *problems* here was a better way.

Comment: Why would that not be allowed? Trying to learn about all of this lol

Comment: @Austin_No_Brain Because in C++ the array size must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz So, what if I would want an array that differs in size each time the user puts in a number? Say he wants a 5x5 one time and the next he wants a 7x7?

Comment: @Austin_No_Brain See the 3rd part of my answer. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Ah, yes. Sorry about that. Thank you for answering